# MiniMax algorithm makes part of the playing field blocked

Tags: c#, algorithm, game-engine, minimax

I'm trying to write a Trap the Cat game based on the MiniMax algorithm. This is the first time I am writing such a project. Faced with the problem that when the algorithm is called, the playing field is strangely filled with blocked "tiles".

Link to the game to make it clear what it is about
[Trap the Cat](https://llerrah.com/cattrap.htm)

I'm pretty sure that the problem lies in some error in the algorithm. But I do not exclude the possibility that, perhaps, the problem is the incorrect transfer of the playing field to the algorithm (as if the transmitted playing field is global, and the algorithm changes it).

[Output from console, after first calling MiniMaxAlgorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz3I8.png)

1 - blocked tiles. 0 - free tiles

Below I attach the full code of the entire program with comments. I tried to paint it as best as possible. I wrote code based on a video course from the Linkedin learning website. The code there is written in python, so I translated everything into c# myself.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static int size;
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Print game field size: ");
        size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] gameField = MakeGameField(size);
        Console.WriteLine("Start field: ");
        PrintGameFieldToConsole(gameField);

        Game(gameField);
    }

    //The method that controls the gameplay
    static void Game(int[,] startGameField)
    {
        int[,] gameField = startGameField;
        while (true)
        {
            int[] characterPos = FindCharacterPosition(gameField);
            //Check for the end of the game. A player's victory or defeat
            if (characterPos[0] == 0 | characterPos[1] == 0 | characterPos[0] == size - 1 | characterPos[1] == size - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GAME LOSED! GOOD LUCK IN NEXT TRY!!!");
                break;
            } 
            if(LegalMoves(gameField, characterPos).Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GAME WON! CONGRATULATIONS!!!");
                break;
            }
            int[] playerMove = GetUserMove(gameField);
            gameField = ApplyMove(gameField, playerMove, false);
            PrintGameFieldToConsole(gameField);

            Console.WriteLine("Cat's move...");
            int[] catMove = MiniMax(gameField);
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Cat move is ({catMove[0]}; {catMove[1]})");
            gameField = ApplyMove(gameField, catMove, true);
            PrintGameFieldToConsole(gameField);
        }
    }

    //Method that returns the player's move
    static int[] GetUserMove(int[,] gameField)
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            int[] playerMove = new int[2];
            Console.Write("Print move (x, y): ");
            string[] userInput = Console.ReadLine().Split(",");
            playerMove[0] = int.Parse(userInput[0]);
            playerMove[1] = int.Parse(userInput[1]);
            if (gameField[playerMove[0], playerMove[1]] != 0) Console.WriteLine("Wrong move. Print other");
            else return playerMove;
        }
    }
    //Method that makes game field based on recieved size. 6 - "cat", placed in center of game field 
    static int[,] MakeGameField(int size)
    {
        int[,] gameField = new int[size, size];
        gameField[size / 2, size / 2] = 6;
        return gameField;
    }
    //Method that print's game field to console
    static void PrintGameFieldToConsole(int[,] gameField)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0) Console.Write(" [ ");
            else Console.Write("[ ");
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (j < size - 1) Console.Write(gameField[i, j] + ", ");
                else Console.Write(gameField[i, j]);
            }
            Console.Write(" ]\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("==================");
    }

    //Minimax algorithm. Returns the best move received when calling the MaxValue method (the best move for the "cat")
    static int[] MiniMax(int[,] upperGame)
    {
        //MaxValue gets the value of mode equal to [-1, -1] as an indicator that the method is being called for the first time.
        int[] startMove = new int[2] { -1, -1 };
        int[,] gameField = upperGame;
        int[] bestMove = MaxValue(gameField, startMove, true).Item1;
        return bestMove;
    }

    //The MaxValue method. A recursive method that returns the best move for the "cat" by checking all the following possible moves of the player
    static Tuple<int[], int> MaxValue(int[,] upperGameField, int[] move, bool maximizingPlayer)
    {
        //A copy of the received game field
        int[,] gameField = upperGameField;
        //Check: is the method called for the first time, or has MinValue already sent some move
        if (move[0] != -1 & move[1] != -1)
        {
            maximizingPlayer = !maximizingPlayer;
            //Changing game field according recieved move
            gameField = ApplyMove(gameField, move, maximizingPlayer);  
        }
        int[] characterPos = FindCharacterPosition(gameField);
        //List of possible moves for the "cat" (free tiles around the "cat")
        List<string> legalMoves = LegalMoves(gameField, characterPos);

        //Terminal node
        if(legalMoves.Count == 0)
        {
            return Tuple.Create(characterPos, (size * size) * GameUtility(gameField, legalMoves, maximizingPlayer));
        }
        int maxValue = int.MinValue;
        int tempMax = maxValue;
        int[] bestMove = Target(legalMoves[0], characterPos);
        //Passing through each possible move, and choosing the best one based on the maxValue variable
        foreach (var legalMove in legalMoves)
        {
            int[] tempMove = Target(legalMove, characterPos);
            tempMax = (int)MathF.Max(maxValue, MinValue(gameField, tempMove, maximizingPlayer));
            if(maxValue < tempMax)
            {
                maxValue = tempMax;
                bestMove = tempMove;
            }
        }
        return Tuple.Create(bestMove, maxValue);
    }
    //MinValue method. A recursive method that returns the best move the player could have made (the worst move for the "cat")
    static int MinValue(int[,] upperGame, int[] move, bool maximizingPlayer)
    {
        //A copy of the received game field
        int[,] gameField = upperGame;
        maximizingPlayer = !maximizingPlayer;
        //Changing game field according recieved move
        gameField = ApplyMove(gameField, move, maximizingPlayer);

        int[] characterPos = FindCharacterPosition(gameField);

        //Terminal node
        if (characterPos[0] == 0 | characterPos[1] == 0 | characterPos[0] == size - 1 | characterPos[1] == size - 1)
        {
            List<string> tempMoves = new List<string>() { "2", "3", "4" };
            return (size * size) * GameUtility(gameField, tempMoves, maximizingPlayer);
        }
        int minValue = int.MaxValue;
        //Passing through all possible moves of the player, and choosing the best move for the player (the worst move for the "cat")
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (gameField[i, j] != 0) continue;

                int[] tempMove = new int[2] { i, j };
                minValue = (int)MathF.Min(minValue, MaxValue(gameField, tempMove, maximizingPlayer).Item2);
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }

    //A method that changes the playing field based on the received move and the Boolean variable maximizingPlayer
    static int[,] ApplyMove(int[,] gameField, int[] move, bool maximizingPlayer)
    {
        if (maximizingPlayer)
        {
            int[] characterPos = FindCharacterPosition(gameField);
            //Remove old "cat"
            gameField[characterPos[0], characterPos[1]] = 0;
            //Place new "cat"
            gameField[move[0], move[1]] = 6;
        }
        //Block tile
        else
        {
            if (gameField[move[0], move[1]] != 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ApplyMove method. Choosen tile isn't free");
                return gameField;
            }
            gameField[move[0], move[1]] = 1;
        }
        return gameField;
    }
    //Getting possible moves for the "cat". The check (i % 2 == 0) is needed due to the fact that the game field is an array of integers with even rows offset
    static List<string> LegalMoves(int[,] gameField, int[] characterPos)
    {
        List<string> possibleMoves = new List<string>();
        if (characterPos[1] > 0 && gameField[characterPos[0], characterPos[1] - 1] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("W");
        if (characterPos[1] < size - 1 && gameField[characterPos[0], characterPos[1] + 1] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("E");
        if (characterPos[0] % 2 == 0)
        {
            if ((characterPos[0] > 0 && characterPos[1] > 0) && gameField[characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1] - 1] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("NW");
            if (characterPos[0] > 0 && gameField[characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1]] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("NE");
            if ((characterPos[0] < size - 1 && characterPos[1] > 0) && gameField[characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1] - 1] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("SW");
            if (characterPos[0] < size - 1 && gameField[characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1]] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("SE");
        }
        else
        {
            if (characterPos[0] > 0 && gameField[characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1]] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("NW");
            if ((characterPos[0] > 0 && characterPos[1] < size - 1) && gameField[characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1] + 1] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("NE");
            if (characterPos[0] < size - 1 && gameField[characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1]] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("SW");
            if ((characterPos[0] < size - 1 && characterPos[1] < size - 1) && gameField[characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1] + 1] == 0) possibleMoves.Add("SE");
        }
        return possibleMoves;
    }
    //A method that returns the position of the desired tile on the game field, based on the recieved move
    static int[] Target(string direction, int[] characterPos)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case "W":
                return new int[2] { characterPos[0], characterPos[1] - 1 };
            case "E":
                return new int[2] { characterPos[0], characterPos[1] + 1 };
            case "NW":
                if (characterPos[0] % 2 == 0) return new int[2] { characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1] - 1 };
                return new int[2] { characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1] };
            case "NE":
                if (characterPos[0] % 2 == 0) return new int[2] { characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1] };
                return new int[2] { characterPos[0] - 1, characterPos[1] + 1 };
            case "SW":
                if (characterPos[0] % 2 == 0) return new int[2] { characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1] - 1 };
                return new int[2] { characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1] };
            case "SE":
                if (characterPos[0] % 2 == 0) return new int[2] { characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1] };
                return new int[2] { characterPos[0] + 1, characterPos[1] + 1 };
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Target method. Unexpected direction");
        return null;
    }

    //A method that checks the state of the game and returns the corresponding value
    static int GameUtility(int[,] gameField, List<string> moves, bool maximizingPlayer)
    {
        int[] characterPos = FindCharacterPosition(gameField);
        if (characterPos[0] == 0 | characterPos[1] == 0 | characterPos[0] == size - 1 | characterPos[1] == size - 1)
        {
            return 100;
        }
        if(moves.Count == 0)
        {
            return -100;
        }

        return ScoreProximity(gameField, maximizingPlayer);
    }

    //A method that considers how good the current playing field is for the "cat"
    static int ScoreProximity(int[,] gameField, bool maximizingPlayer)
    {
        List<int> distances = new List<int>() { 100, 100 };
        int[] characterPos = FindCharacterPosition(gameField);
        List<string> moves = LegalMoves(gameField, characterPos);
        foreach(var move in moves)
        {
            int dist = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                dist++;
                int[] tempMove = Target(move, characterPos);
                if (tempMove[0] < 0 | tempMove[1] >= size | tempMove[1] < 0 | tempMove[1] >= size) break;
                if (gameField[tempMove[0], tempMove[1]] != 0)
                {
                    dist *= 5;
                    break;
                }
            }
            distances.Add(dist);
        }
        distances.Sort();
        return size * 2 - (maximizingPlayer ? distances[0] : distances[1]);
    }

    //Method that returns the current position of the "cat" on the game field
    static int[] FindCharacterPosition(int[,] gameField)
    {
        int[] characterPos = new int[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (gameField[i, j] == 6)
                {
                    characterPos[0] = i;
                    characterPos[1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return characterPos;
    } 
}
```

I tried to save all the previous moves of the player, and after calling MiniMax, return the game field to the correct state. But it didn't help. And I think that the problem lies in the algorithm, respectively, this only hides the problem of a poorly working algorithm

Comment: Thrice in your code you use logical OR, you probably want conditional OR instead.

Comment: I have a total of 12 operators | in the code. I don't understand what you're talking about. And it seems to me (maybe I'm wrong) that in none of the cases of using the operator | there is no difference between conditional and logical OR.

I tried to change the logical OR to conditional OR in different places, but no change helped solve the problem.

Comment: I found an error in the ApplyMove() method. The code inside the if/else statements had to be swapped. Since a method should be called from MaxValue to lock one tile, and in MinValue a method should be called to move the "cat".

But this does not solve the problem. Moreover, another problem has appeared. Now the game completely fills the playing field

[Screenshot from console after swapping if/else](https://imgur.com/5N1s1Y7)

Comment: I also attach a photo with the algorithm execution process (I output the current state of the field to the console, after the ApplyMove() method inside MaxValue()). Judging by the process, the algorithm is not working correctly. And most likely it needs to be rewritten. But I really hope that someone will find some stupid mistake and give advice on how to solve it

[Algorithm process](https://imgur.com/sSi8vxG)

Comment: What I would do is, log everything, make the thing runnable frame by frame, use unit testing against an expected case and throw accordingly when something is wrong. This way you can't go wrong and you will spot the error immediately.